# What happens when you drop a primary key constraint that has a foreign key attached to it in Oracle and then re-enable the primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Okay so say you have 2 tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1`'s primary key is the foreign key to `Table2`. If you drop the primary key constraint on `Table1` and then re-enable it with `Alter Table` command, would the foreign key on Table2 automatically be re-enabled also?

Comment: No, the reference is destroyed. You need to reset the foreign key to get the new reference to the primary key. Take a looke here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629087/foreign-key-reference-target-does-not-exist

Comment: In mysql you cannot roll back ddl statements, so I don't think you meant this question for mysql.

Comment: @RyffLe is it Completely Destroyed or is it just disabled? After the table is rolled back to its original state can I alter Table2 and re-enable the constraint?

Comment: Is this an Oracle question? You cannot roll back DDL in Oracle

Comment: It's completly destoryed. you need to ALTER the table to restore the key

Comment: @RyffLe thank you and I just now realized that I did not mean to drop the table, I meant drop the Primary Key Constraint then re-enable the PK Constraint.

Comment: Same here, ORACLE deletes it from the tasks of the constraint, which he UNIQUE INDEX when switching off the primary key constraint.
As a result, the storage options (LOCAL + partition information) are lost! If you do not know, this behavior is extremely heard and may be the possible behavior would be DB negative behavior. It was not for nothing that a local primary keys constraint was deliberately held in advance.

Comment: If you want to find more on this topic, I can recommend this page to you: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-primary-key/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try what happens.

First create tables t1 and t2.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (parent_id NUMBER);
Table created
CREATE TABLE t2 (child_id NUMBER);
Table created
```

and then create the 2 constraints

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (parent_id) USING INDEX;
Table altered
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD CONSTRAINT t2_fk FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES t1;
Table altered
```

now look at the dictionary and select the constraints of the 2 tables

```
SELECT c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, c.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM User_Constraints c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME IN ('T1', 'T2');
CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ --------------- ------------------------------
T1_PK                          P               
T2_FK                          R               T1_PK
```

we see 1 primary key (P) and 1 foreign key (R)
Then drop the pk

```
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP CONSTRAINT t1_pk CASCADE;
Table altered
```

the cascade keyword instructs oracle to implicitly drop all fk constraints referencing the pk to drop. Without cascade you will get *ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys* and the pk is not dropped.

again look at the dictionary and select the constraints of the 2 tables

```
SELECT c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, c.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM User_Constraints c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME IN ('T1', 'T2');
CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ --------------- ------------------------------
```

no rows - pk and fk are gone. recreate pk

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (parent_id) USING INDEX;
Table altered
```

and look at the dictionary

```
SELECT c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, c.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM User_Constraints c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME IN ('T1', 'T2');
CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ --------------- ------------------------------
T1_PK                          P
```

only the pk is created. cleanup testcase

```
DROP TABLE t2;
Table dropped
DROP TABLE t1;
Table dropped
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a test case of what you asked. I hope I understood correctly the premises:

- I have a table MY_PK with a primary key on column C1
- I have a table MY_FK with contains a primary key on column C1 which is also a FOREIGN KEY to column C1 in table MY_PK.
- You want to disable or drop the primary key in table MY_FK to see what happens with the FOREIGN KEY.

Let's play:

```
SQL> create table my_pk ( c1 number primary key , c2 number );

Table created.

SQL> create table my_fk ( c1 number primary key , c2 number, constraint my_fk_constraint foreign key (c1) references my_pk (c1) ) ;

Table created.

SQL>  select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, status from dba_constraints where table_name in ( 'MY_FK' , 'MY_PK' ) and owner = 'MYOWNER' ;

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ - --------
MY_PK                          SYS_C00141013                  P ENABLED
MY_FK                          SYS_C00141016                  P ENABLED
MY_FK                          MY_FK_CONSTRAINT               R ENABLED
```

So, let's do what you asked:

**Disable Primary Key in table MY_FK which is also a foreign key to Table MY_PK**

```
SQL> alter table my_fk disable primary key ;

Table altered.

SQL>  select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, status from dba_constraints where table_name in ( 'MY_FK' , 'MY_PK' ) and owner = 'MY_OWNER';

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ - --------
MY_PK                          SYS_C00141013                  P ENABLED
MY_FK                          SYS_C00141016                  P DISABLED
MY_FK                          MY_FK_CONSTRAINT               R ENABLED
```

Let's evaluate whether the foreign key is still enforced, even the pk is disabled. You can see above that the FK appears in the dictionary as ENABLED.

```
SQL> insert into my_pk values ( 1 , 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into my_fk values ( 2, 1 );
insert into my_fk values ( 2, 1 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYOWNER.MY_FK_CONSTRAINT) violated - parent
key not found
```

The foreign key is still enforced, although the PK is disabled and you can still insert duplicates if you want

```
SQL> insert into my_fk values ( 1 , 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL>
```

We re-enable back again the PK in table MY_FK

```
SQL> alter table my_fk enable primary key ;

Table altered.

SQL>  select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, status from dba_constraints where table_name in ( 'MY_FK' , 'MY_PK' ) ;

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ - --------
MY_PK                          SYS_C00141013                  P ENABLED
MY_FK                          SYS_C00141016                  P ENABLED
MY_FK                          MY_FK_CONSTRAINT               R ENABLED
```

**Drop the Primary Key in table MY_FK which is also a Foreign key to MY_PK**

```
SQL> alter table my_fk drop primary key ;

Table altered.

SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, status from dba_constraints 
where table_name in ( 'MY_FK' , 'MY_PK' ) ;

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ - --------
MY_PK                          SYS_C00141013                  P ENABLED
MY_FK                          MY_FK_CONSTRAINT               R ENABLED

SQL> insert into my_pk values ( 2 , 2 );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from my_pk ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2

SQL> insert into my_fk values ( 2 ,2 );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from my_fk ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2

SQL> insert into my_fk values ( 3 , 3 );
insert into my_fk values ( 3 , 3 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYOWNER.MY_FK_CONSTRAINT) violated - parent
key not found
```

So, either with the primary key constraint disabled or dropped in table MY_FK, the foreign key is still enforced. Obviously, you can add duplicates to the table meanwhile the primary key is disabled. I did not use the option CASCADE in my test case, which changes to the scenario provided in the other answer.